# Why is Ember-Cli 3.14 throwing an ESLint No-New-Mixin error

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, eslint

I have three custom mixins that no longer work in Ember-Cli 3.14 (I had to step back down to 3.13.2). All I get is an Ember error saying `no-new-mixins` for each of the mixins. While the WebUI compiles and is hosted, the WebUI that is accessible no longer works properly. The errors appear to be thrown by ESLint.

Has anyone else had this problem with Ember 3.14?

https://github.com/ember-cli/eslint-plugin-ember/blob/master/docs/rules/no-new-mixins.md

I am hesitant to ignore a rule just because it does not get along with a new version of Ember, but works in others. So, I am checking with SO first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Ember team has decided to move away from mixins going forward so this linting rule was added in that release to alert developers of this decision. Here's an [RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/issues/534) discussing a plan to move away from them.

It looks like you can suppress this particular error by modifying your `eslint.rc` file like so:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    'ember'
  ],
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended'
  ],
  rules: {
    'ember/no-new-mixins': 'off'
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if this will override all rules or just that particular one so you might want to look into that a bit more. More info can be found in the [README](https://github.com/ember-cli/eslint-plugin-ember).

Comment: I think the intend of that lint rule is not to be disabled globally if you have mixins but to whitelist the existing ones using `//eslint-disable-next-line ember/no-no-mixins` and to prevent new ones from being added. Otherwise the name would not make much sense. ;-)

Comment: @jelhan It appears you provided a commented code snippet. To confirm, can you please provide the code snippet that would whitelist existing mixins? In the meantime, I need to look I to migrating to class decorators.

Comment: @JWeezy You could disable eslint rules per file or per line using inline comments. Please find more details [in ESLint config](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments). There is no need to migrate to native classes asap. Ember's core team has committed to support both classic and native classes, for quite some time. You could also still use mixins with native classes.